# Keyboard acts strangely when using Chrome with certain web apps

Tags: macos, keyboard, text, formatting

When I use Chrome to type text in Dropbox Paper, Wordpress Custom CSS or Facebook, the keyboard acts strangely. When I want to remove a character, two characters get removed instead of one, and when I use the enter key, there are two new lines instead of one.

Safari works fine.

I am on a MacBook Pro 2017.

Does someone have a solution for this?

Comment: If these are web apps, can you list which browsers or versions you use? If you are using an app to edit text, add that too. My suspicion is JavaScript to process your keystrokes is lagging and causing timing errors and glitches or it’s broken ( ad blockers or just plain old broken code).

Comment: @bmike Thanks for helping, I am currently using Google Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Build officiel) (64 bits). I tried to use Dropbox Paper, Facebook and Additional CSS (Wordpress) on Safari and it's working fine. Is there a way to solve this in Google Chrome?